# UIScrollView.appearance().delegate an error

Tags: swiftui

Hello everyone I have this code

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @State private var didLoad = true
    init() {
        UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = viewModel.isOnTop
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        }
        .onAppear() {
            if self.didLoad {
                self.didLoad.toggle()
                UIScrollView.appearance().delegate = viewModel.self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I also have this code in ContentView

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { _ in
                    NavigationLink(destination: {Detail()}, label: {Text("title")})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I go to the Detail, exit to List and go to the Detail I have this error: collectionView:shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
How can I fix it??????

I try add didload but with out responce

Comment: when I click on detail then I go to the menu and go again I see the following error: collectionView:shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: How does one refer to UIScrollView in a SwiftUI app?

Comment: @kirikprogramist please include a [mre]. You refer to a `viewModel`, which appears no where in your included code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.